# Unable to copy RDS parameter group across regions

Tags: aws-cli

I am using the RDS command line tool from [here](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/2928) and am having trouble copying the parameter group to a different region. Running the rds-copy-db-parameter-group fails with the following error:

`rds-copy-db-parameter-group:  Could not find the resource you requested: DB ParameterGroup not found, not allowed to do cross region copy.`

The command I am using is:

`rds-copy-db-parameter-group arn:aws:rds:ap-southeast-1:myAccntId:pg:myParamGroup-utf8mb4 -t copyOfMyParam -td testcopy`

I'm pretty sure the ARN is correct and the parameter does exist. Is this a problem with the tool or aws? Is anyone else encountering a similar issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this same issue recently and opened a support ticket with AWS. The response I got was that the RDS team added this feature to the documentation but haven't yet built the actual support for this feature.

Comment: This appears to still be the case (at least for `copy-db-cluster-parameter-group`) as I'm running into the same error over 2 years after this response.

Answer (score 2):

This bothered me a lot and ate up a couple of hours so I put this simple script together. There's loads of room for improvement so please share if you improve upon it or find issues!

https://gist.github.com/phill-tornroth/f0ef50f9402c7c94cbafd8c94bbec9c9

Comment: working like a charm, download the python script and run "python cp-parameter-group.py us-west-1:source_pg us-west-2:target_pg"

Comment: Can't believe that 6 years later, aws does still not seem to support this. Anyways, problem with the attached script is that it ignores that parameter description requests return paginated results, so you'll miss parameters in next pages. Modified [royal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133934/royal)'s script a bit to deal with it (and added a bit more, such as `python3`) at: https://github.com/pchatzou/copy-aws-rds-parameter-group. Feel free to use, fork, PR etc.